# How to set output device when building a video conference call with Agora

Tags: javascript, agora.io

I'm currently working on a project using Agora to build a video conference call and was wondering how I would set output devices? Other examples of this I've seen only change local tracks from their Video tag with .setSinkID but Ive had no luck trying to use this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the Web SDK. You can call the [`setPlaybackDevice`](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/ilocalaudiotrack.html#setplaybackdevice) method on each track along with the output Device ID, which can be retrieved by calling [`getPlaybackDevices`](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/iagorartc.html#getplaybackdevices).